# Is it possible to hide TODO timestamps in Org mode?

Tags: org-mode, todo

Is it possible to hide TODO timestamps in Org mode?  More specifically, I want to keep the timestamps associated with TODO states (CLOSED, SCHEDULED, DEADLINE) from being shown in the Org buffer, even if they exist in the file.

Why?  I'm working on the same file in both Emacs and Orgzly (Org app for Android).  I don't use timestamps in Emacs, but Orgzly puts them in by default and has no option not to do so, although it does allow you to hide them in its UI.

Comment: Yes, just adjust the regexp in the example of the following thread entitled **"Completely hide the :PROPERTIES: drawer in org-mode"**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478260/completely-hide-the-properties-drawer-in-org-mode